# iOS Facebook SDK, Games Start Playing post

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

im trying to implement a method in my native iOS game the publish a story on face book such as this photo
[image: Facebook Activitys]

most games that is integrated with facebook share stories like this in the activity section on the timeline

any good example especially for iOS 6

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called "actions". Here is how to post an action.

```
// create an Open Graph action
id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
[action setObject:objectId forKey:@"dish"];

// create action referencing user owned object
[FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"/me/fbogsample:eat" graphObject:action completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
  if(!error) {
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"OG story posted, story id: %@", [result objectForKey:@"id"]]);
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"OG story posted"
                                message:@"Check your Facebook profile or activity log to see the story."
                               delegate:self
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
  } else {
    // An error occurred
    NSLog(@"Encountered an error posting to Open Graph: %@", error);
  }
}];
```

However, before you post a question about Facebook open-graph in general, you should check [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/open-graph) first.